# Checking the user email and password

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to validate if the email and password in the form are true, so that I can redirect it to a new page. But, when I reload the page it doesn't validate if the user email and the user password are correct it does actually nothing.  It only gives me back the user email and password it needs to check.

```js
 var app = angular
    .module('formValidation', ['ui-router'])
    .controller("locationFormCtrl", locationFormCtrl);
    // .config('$stateprovider','$urlRouterProvider',routeFunc);

    function locationFormCtrl($http,config){
      $http.post(config.apiUrl+ "login", {email: "ehnk@gmail.nl", password: "welkom123"}).then(function(response){
          if(email == "audrey@appsharing.nl" & password == "welkom123"){
            header('Location : opdrachten.html');
          }else{
            alert('wrong password');
          }
      });
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>Login Form</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="formValidation" ng-controller="locationFormCtrl" >
  <form novalidate class="simple-form" ng-submit="submit()">
   <label>Email: <input type="text" ng-model="user.email" name="email"/></label><br>
   <label>Password: <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" name="password" required/></label><br>
   <input type="submit"  value="login">
  </form>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: `header()` is a php method. php doesn't run in the browser

Comment: Also, anybody can look at the source code and see the login

Comment: Thanks!! I forgot that

Answer (score 1):

```
//please update condition as below..

if(email == "audrey@appsharing.nl" && password == "welkom123"){
   header('Location : opdrachten.html');
}else{
   alert('wrong password');
}
```

Comment: You were missed & inyour condition